# Trying to write a VBA to set all Format control Dropdown values to 0

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

Wandering if any one can help. been trying to create a macro that resets all dropdowns to 0 (Format control)

So far i have this but i get an error saying " unable to set the value property of the dropdown class"

```
Sub callmacro()

Const NAME As String = "Drop Down"
Dim dropdown As Shape
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pricing Tool")


On Error Resume Next
For Each dropdown In Sht.Shapes


If Left(dropdown.NAME, 9) = NAME Then


dropdown.ControlFormat.Value = 0

On Error GoTo 0

End If

Next dropdown
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The code seems to work for me. Try `Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pricing Tool")` see if that helps maybe.

Comment: Or insteadof `.value`, try  `.ListIndex`. Are you using a Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do it using the `.Shapes` collection. It can get messy vey easily if you have other types of shapes in your worksheet.

Instead, assuming that you have already assigned some list to your ComboBoxes (if you haven't added at least one item to all of them it will throw an error), I would use the hidden collection `.DropDowns` like so:

```
Option Explicit

Sub InitializeDropDown()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim dd As DropDown
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pricing Tool")
For Each dd In sht.DropDowns
    If dd.ListCount > 0 Then
        dd.Value = 0
    End If
Next dd
End Sub
```

This initializes your Combo Boxes to blank.

Note that this code works for Form Control Combo boxes and not for ActiveX Combo boxes.

**EDIT:**

As FunThomas pointed out you can easily check if an item has been added to the Combo Box. The relevant If-statement has been added.

Comment: I knew there was something like the `DropDowns`-collection but coudn't find it. This is of course much easier. Just add the check `If dd.ListCount > 0` to prevent the runtime error when a dropdown has no list assigned and I will going to delete my answer as it is useless.

Comment: @FunThomas Hehe it's hidden! Thanks for the suggestion. The check has been added. :)

Comment: Thanks this helped alot! i didnt know about the hidden .Dropdown that helps!